# What are the main features of radare2?

Tags: tools, binary-analysis, radare2

[Radare2](http://radare.org/y/) is a framework for reverse-engineering gathering several tools (see this [Phrack article](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=66&id=14#article) about radare1 to know a bit more about the framework).

I would like to know if someone could point out the main useful features of the framework for reverse engineering ? And, particularly what makes radare2 different from other tools or frameworks ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

from its [feature](http://radare.org/y/?p=features) page:

- Multi-architecture and multi-platform

  - GNU/Linux, Android, *BSD, OSX, iPhoneOS, Windows{32,64} and Solaris
  - x86{16,32,64}, dalvik, avr, arm, java, powerpc, sparc, mips, bf, csr, m86k, msil, sh
  - pe{32,64}, [fat]mach0{32,64}, elf{32,64}, te, dex and java classes
- Highly scriptable

  - Vala, Go, Python, Guile, Ruby, Perl, Lua, Java, JavaScript, sh, ..
  - batch mode and native plugins with full internal API access
  - native scripting based in mnemonic commands and macros
- Hexadecimal editor

  - 64bit offset support with virtual addressing and section maps
  - Assemble and disassemble from/to many architectures
  - colorizes opcodes, bytes and debug register changes
  - print data in various formats (int, float, disasm, timestamp, ..)
  - search multiple patterns or keywords with binary mask support
  - checksumming and data analysis of byte blocks
- IO is wrapped

  - support Files, disks, processes and streams
  - virtual addressing with sections and multiple file mapping
  - handles gdb:// and rap:// remote protocols
- Filesystems support

  - allows to mount ext2, vfat, ntfs, and many others
  - support partition types (gpt, msdos, ..)
- Debugger support

  - gdb remote and **brainfuck** debugger support
  - software and hardware breakpoints
  - tracing and logging facilities
- Diffing between two functions or binaries

  - graphviz friendly code analysis graphs
  - colorize nodes and edges
- Code analysis at opcode, basicblock, function levels

  - embedded simple virtual machine to emulate code
  - keep track of code and data references
  - function calls and syscall decompilation
  - function description, comments and library signatures